# How to copy and paste shapes in KineticJS

Tags: javascript, canvas, kineticjs

I have a button1 like this.

```
var Button1 = new Kinetic.Polygon({
            points: [0, 0, 0, 30, 15, 15],
            fill: 'rgb(0, 255, 0)'
        });
```

Now I want to copy it (duplicate it). How would I do that?

I tried this -

```
    var Button2 = new Kinetic.Polygon();
    Button2 = Button1;
```

This did not work as only one copy is being drawn on the canvas.

How should I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simplest way to copy an object in KineticJS is to use the clone method:

```
 var Button1 = new Kinetic.Polygon({
        points: [0, 0, 0, 30, 15, 15],
        fill: 'rgb(0, 255, 0)'
 });

 var Button2 = Button1.clone();
```

Button2 is now an exact copy of Button1

Comment: also, dont forget to do layer.add(Button2); and layer.draw(); so that the object appears on the stage.

Comment: This is the official way to copy and paste so I am going to accept this. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: you can also pass in parameters in the clone method to override those in the original object like Button1.clone({fill: 'rgb(0, 123, 0)'}); which means it will have the same points but different fill.

Comment: Thanks Eric, big fan of your library.

Answer (score 0):

What about this:

```
var buttonData = {
            points: [0, 0, 0, 30, 15, 15],
            fill: 'rgb(0, 255, 0)'
        }

var Button1 = new Kinect.Polygon(buttonData);
var Button2 = new Kinect.Polygon(buttonData);
```

?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I never thought about that. but is this method better or the $.extend() (in terms of performance and which one is more commoon)

Answer (score 0):

Button1 and Button2 now point to the same Kinetic object.

You can try to use jQuery extend method

```
var Button2 = $.extend({}, Button1);
```

This will make a copy of the object.

Comment: The .clone() method is better and built-into KineticJS.